# Why does echo-ing "<! <" return "<! >"?

Tags: php, echo

Here is my exact code.

```
<?php
echo "<! <";
?>
```

And this is the returned string.

```
<! >
```

Why is the last character changing?

Comment: not for me. how are you running this?

Comment: As viewed where...? Raw output? In a browser?

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this error either.

Comment: Because you're _intoxicated_? :-)

Comment: Is this the only place the code is used perhaps you copy and pasted a second line but didn't make a change?

Comment: If you open this php script in google chrome and look at the source it will show `<! >`, but i don't think this has anything to do with PHP. My guess is that chrome is trying to fix invalid markup or something.

Comment: it happened in chrome and not other browser. :)

Comment: Yes, it happens in Chrome when viewing source, but apparently not in other browsers. What's so hard about showing source as it exists?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have created an identical script as that detailed by the OP.

In Firefox v3.6.3, the browser displays `<! <`.

In Google Chrome v4.1, the browser display is *blank*, but the source shows `<! >`.

In Internet Explorer 8, the browser displays `<! <`.

In Opera v10.53, the browser displays `<` and the source shows `<! <`.

Not sure which browser you are having difficulties in, or, for that matter, why you would be wanting to display these characters in a browser window.

If you are wanting these characters to be displayed, literally, then using something like `htmlentities()` to convert these characters into HTML characters which will be displayed through the browser, would be the recommended way to make that happen.

Comment: I was looking at Google Chrome source, which apparently is the only browser to show the wrong source. So this would be a Chrome issue of not actually displaying the correct source.

Originally encountered when making RSS feeds with <content:encoded> tags which contain CDATA sections in which an extraneous > appears in Chrome source.

    <?php
    echo "<item><content:encoded><![CDATA[<div>content</div>]]>  </content:encoded></item>";
    ?>

If it is a Chrome issue then I guess the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

if you give it a "Content-Type: text/plain" header, chrome should render it normally.

it's possible you are either sending a "text/html" header or not sending a Content-Type header at all, so the browser must guess what kind of content it is.